# Report on multiple, multi-select picklists value frequency.

Tags: reporting, picklist, dashboard

someone has an example for this code? I need report 5, 6 multipicklist fields. I tried the app *multipick list frequency*, but it's limited to management an only field.

For e.g. I have 3 records:

A - Dog, cat
B - Dog
C - Cat, Bird, Elephant.

I need that my report show in a chart:

2 dogs, 2 cats, 1 bird, 1 elephant.

Thanks in advance for attention.